# Split number range at every hundred

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code that I found elsewhere and I'm trying to figure out how I can get it to stop appending to a range if it reaches the next hundred.

RI'll have a list like [600-650, 700-820, 850-870, 1700-2120] and I want it to turn into [600-650, 700-799, 800-820, 850-870, 1700-1799, 1800-1899, 1900-1999, 2000-2099, 2100-2120]

I was thinking I could check to see if the last two numbers are 99 and if so, stop and then start again at the next number.  I'm not sure how to implement that.

The code is below:

```
def get_line_numbers_concat(line_nums):
    seq = []
    final = []
    last = 0

    for index, val in enumerate(line_nums):

        if last + 1 == val or index == 0:
            seq.append(val)
            last = val
        else:
            if len(seq) > 1:
               final.append(str(seq[0]) + '-' + str(seq[len(seq)-1]))
            else:
               final.append(str(seq[0]))
            seq = []
            seq.append(val)
            last = val

        if index == len(line_nums) - 1:
            if len(seq) > 1:
                final.append(str(seq[0]) + '-' + str(seq[len(seq)-1]))
            else:
                final.append(str(seq[0]))

    final_str = ', '.join(map(str, final))
    return final_str
```

Comment: Can you give a better idea of what you want your output to be and what format your input is it? How do you call `get_line_number_concat`?

Comment: I'll have a list like [600-650, 700-820, 850-870, 1700-2120] and I want it to turn into [600-650, 700-799, 800-820, 850-870, 1700-1799, 1800-1899, 1900-1999, 2000-2099, 2100-2120]

Comment: That doesn't seem to match what your code does. Also `600-650` is just the literal `(-50)`. It's important to know how you're calling the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def convert_range_every_hundred(ranges):
    ranges.sort()
    for begin, end in ranges:
        while (begin // 100 + 1) * 100 - 1 < end:
            yield begin, (begin // 100 + 1) * 100 - 1
            begin = (begin // 100 + 1) * 100
        yield begin, end
```

Testing:

```
my_list = [
    (600, 650), 
    (700, 820),
    (850, 870), 
    (1700, 2120),
]

result = list(convert_range_every_hundred(my_list))
print(result)
```

That prints:

```
[(600, 650),
 (700, 799),
 (800, 820),
 (850, 870),
 (1700, 1799),
 (1800, 1899),
 (1900, 1999),
 (2000, 2099),
 (2100, 2120)]
```